# PHP Image Downloader

Tags: php, image, curl, download

Hey guys I'm looking for help downloading 1000+ images from one of my vendors for an e-commerce site. They provided me with the proper URLs which I set up in an array but I can't seem to get any PHP scripts I find to functionally download the images.

I have:

```
ArrayOf1000ULRS[];

Loop through Array
   -save_image(URL)
```

Example function I found online:

```
function save_image($img,$fullpath){
$ch = curl_init ($img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($fullpath)){
    unlink($fullpath);
}
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: `if ($rawdata === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` is one extra little thing you could have. curl doesn't always succeed.

Comment: Also, what exactly "is not working"? Have the files been created at all (but empty) or not? Also make sure that the apache-user may write to `$fullpath`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($fileNames as $url)
{
set_time_limit(0);
//Get the filename from the end of the URL.
$imgName = explode("/", $url);
//Used this to run multiple scripts.
//Basically don't download files you have.
if(!file_exists("./images/".$imgName[-int-]))
{
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen("./images/".$imgName[-int-],'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're on a *nix machine, you could just throw a system call in there and use WGET.

```
foreach($arrayOfImages as $url){
    $cmd = "wget $url";
    system($cmd);
}
```

insecure as heck but if this is a one time personal thing I say do it.